# C spliting strings into an array outputs just the first token

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am writing a microshell program as homework at my university. 
Everything goes well besides one function that's not doing exactly what I'd wish it did.

I am quite new to C programming, always used higher level languages. 
In fact the only times I worked with C was fiddling around with Arduino.

So I've got a line of what user inputs on the prompt. I'm trying to split it into an array of strings separated by space.
I initialized an array with

```
    char **args = NULL;
    args = malloc(sizeof(char *) * LINE_LENGTH);
```

And I'm sending it to a function parse_line(line, args)

The function looks like this:

```
bool parse_line(char *line, char **arr) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *point;
    point = strtok(line, " ");
    while (point != NULL) {
        arr[i] = malloc(strlen(point) + 1);
        strcpy(arr[i], point);
        point = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    arr[i] = NULL;

    if (!arr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

The thing is that afterwards in the arr resides only first token from the splitted up line. 
I am debugging it and though variable 'point' gets the right values, they aren't copied into my array. Why? I don't know.

Oh.. and the line is an array of chars, dynamic one.

```
char * line = NULL;
line = read_input_line();
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 50

void clear_screen();
void display_prompt(bool clearscr);
char * read_input_line();
void print_line(char *line);
bool parse_line(char *line, char **arr);

int main() {
    bool initialRun = true;

    while (true) {
        // display prompt on the screen
        display_prompt(initialRun);
        if (initialRun)
            initialRun = false;

        // read input line from terminal
        char * line = NULL;
        line = read_input_line();

        // basic commands
        if (line == NULL)
            continue;
        if (strcmp(line, "exit") == 0) {
            free(line);
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else if (strcmp(line, "clear") == 0) {
            clear_screen();
            continue;
        }

        // parse line into array
        char **args = NULL;
        args = malloc(sizeof(char *) * LINE_LENGTH);
        if (!parse_line(line, args)) {
            printf("Error during parsing command \n");
            continue;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void clear_screen() {
    printf("\e[2J\e[H");
}

void display_prompt(bool clearscr) {
    if (clearscr)
        clear_screen();
    printf(" >  ");
}

char * read_input_line() {
    char * line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * LINE_LENGTH);
    if (!fgets(line, LINE_LENGTH, stdin))
        return NULL;
    size_t len = strlen(line);
    if (len > 0 && line[len-1] == '\n') {
        line[--len] = '\0';
    }
    return line;
}

void print_line(char *line) {
    printf("%s \n", line);
}

bool parse_line(char *line, char **arr) {
    size_t i = 0;
    char *point;
    point = strtok(line, " ");
    while (point != NULL) {
        arr[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(point) + 1);
        strcpy(arr[i], point);
        point = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    arr[i] = NULL;

    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }

    if (!arr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Input:

```
ls -l -h
```

Comment: Works fine for me, what did you give as input to test it? Can you provide the main() function?

Comment: I've added function which reads line from the terminal.

Comment: What input did you try, because this program runs fine: https://pastebin.com/wxX8Zc48

Comment: I don't need the newline character, so I tried to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm testing it on e.g 'ls -l -h'

Comment: I've added a loop to print out what resides in array after strtok loop and it prints out just three (null)'s

Comment: How are you printing it? Do you mean the arr array or the line array?

Comment: I'm printing the arr array, just like you did in pastebin code.

Comment: And if you copy and paste my code, does that work, because if tit doesnt it might be something entirely different.

Comment: This is ultra weird now. Copy-pasted your code and that's what I'm getting:
error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YHxC8MCJ Try this one, it shouldn't have that error and be more relevant since your edits ( updated the link)

Comment: Okay on another machine with another compiler I'm just getting seg faults.

Comment: error: assigning to 'char *' from incompatible type 'void *'
and error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'void *'

Comment: That should not happen since malloc doesn't have to be typecasted to the appropriate pointer.

Comment: If you're getting that message, you're not using a C compiler; that's a C++ error message.

Comment: char *line = (char *) malloc( ... ) Should fix the error. Also for arr[i] = (char *) malloc (....)

Comment: Yup, sorry I mistakekenly made test project with c++ compiler in IDE. Sorry again. Your code works.

Comment: Still just (null)'s and seg fault on linux.

Comment: Don't have to apologize, we just concluded the code you provided works.
So apparently there is a different issue.
On linux can you ltrace the program and check what function segfaults?      ltrace ./foo

Comment: This is my whole code: https://pastebin.com/fFWu3W3H

Comment: Oh a [mcve], we can help you now.

Comment: I found the problem: for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
That should be printf( .. , arr[j]) instead

Comment: Ltrace log https://pastebin.com/27T9P6kx

Comment: You were printing the i'th index instead of the j'th index, obviously the i'th index is at the location where you put arr[i] = NULL to note the end of the array of c_strings, printing memory adress NULL is not permitted and thus resulted in a segfault.

Comment: Well it's the only problem in your code and the reason it seemed like your arr was filled with NULL's

Comment: Yes, but that's not my biggest concern. The thing is that still inside parse_line I can print out all tokens from arr and outside in main when I'm printing out args array there is just one, first element.

Comment: Nope not when you iterate over it, I can't seem to reproduce your error

Comment: Either way thanks a lot for interest. I'll fight it myself.

Answer (score -1):

```
arr[i] = NULL;
for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
}
```

You are not using `j` as index so you send `NULL` to `printf()`. It's undefined behavior.

---

I propose you an example of implementation(still not the best but for a beginner that enough):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH 50

char **parse_line(char *line, size_t *n);

int main(void) {
    while (true) {
        // display prompt on the screen
        printf(" >  ");

        // read input line from terminal
        char line[LINE_LENGTH];
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            return 1;
        }
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';

        if (strcmp(line, "exit") == 0) {
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        } else if (strcmp(line, "clear") == 0) {
            printf("\e[2J\e[H");
            continue;
        }

        // parse line into array
        size_t n;
        char **args = parse_line(line, &n);
        if (!args) {
            printf("Error during parsing command \n");
            continue;
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", args[i]);
        }
    }
}

char **parse_line(char *line, size_t *n) {
    char **arr = malloc(sizeof *arr);
    size_t i = 0;
    for (char *token = strtok(line, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        char **tmp = realloc(arr, sizeof *tmp * (i + 2));
        if (tmp == NULL) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                free(arr[j]);
            }
            free(arr);
            return NULL;
        }
        arr = tmp;
        arr[i] = malloc(strlen(token) + 1);
        if (arr[i] == NULL) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                free(arr[j]);
            }
            free(arr);
            return NULL;
        }
        strcpy(arr[i], token);
        i++;
    }
    arr[i] = NULL;
    *n = i;
    return arr;
}
```